# Shutting down from X without a desktop environment

Tags: linux, shutdown, non-root-user

I have recently given up my Desktop Environment and am now only using a Window Manager (i3) and X. It all works very well and I do not miss much. Except for one thing: the shutdown button. I can now only shutdown by issuing:

`sudo shutdown -Ph now`

from a terminal. This works, but I want to create a keybinding in i3 to shutdown by clicking `Mod+x`. And I am not sure how this can be achieved. If I create a script in say `~/shutdown` and refer to this with:

`bindsym $mod+x exec ~/shutdown`

Then this does not work; I figure because I am running as a regular user and I am sudoing in this script. I would be fine  with having a terminal appear and prompting me for the password (although I prefer this to not require a password, if possible), but am not sure how to do this. What is a way to get this done?

Using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use [D-Bus sessions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/D-Bus) and [ConsoleKit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ConsoleKit) (which is a default component of most modern desktop systems, so you may already have it installed), a system **poweroff** approach that is slightly cleaner than `sudo shutdown` and that does not require any sort of root privilege is:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" \
 /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

Similarly, a system **restart** can be accomplished with

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" \
  /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

You can put those in scripts and add shortcuts or menu entries to call them.

Comment: While a bit more complicated than a sudo command, I agree this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have sudo not prompt for the password.
Add the following to your /etc/sudoers file (replacing johndoe with your user)

```
johndoe ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, i3 allows you to bind either on [keycodes or on keysyms](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings).

So, you could put an entry in your `sudoers` file, like:

```
plua  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown
```

which would authorize user `plua` to be able to shutdown without issuing a password, and then create a key bind to that effect, such as:

```
bind Mod+x exec /path/to/shutdownscript
```